# cordova android can not display chinese character

Tags: cordova, internationalization

I am now using Cordova to develop android app in hybrid solution. Everything went pretty smoothly until I need to provide multi-language support.
I am using backbone and using r.js to minimize the whole project. After minimization, if I run my app in web browser, the Chinese character can be displayed corrected, but after I exported it into android app and run it in my cell phone as mobile application, the Chinese character is totally messed up and can not be displayed correctly at all.
Are there anything I need to do if I need to provide Chinese support in android app? 
Thanks